# Converting a string tuple to a read tuple

Tags: python, string, tuples

I would like to convert the following list of string tuples to a list of tuples.

Before:

```
mylist = ['(ytz_q2, 99)', '(yda_q2, 45)', '(fta_q2, 56)', '(kta_q2, 1)']
```

After:

```
[(ytz_q2, 99), (yda_q2, 45), (fta_q2, 56), (kta_q2, 1)]
```

My attempt:

So I tried to fix one element before I loop over them but I get an error.

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval(mylist[0])
```

Error:

```
ValueError: malformed string
```

I found a couple of similar threads but their solutions didn't work for me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is that you are trying to evaluate `ytz_q2` as variable not string. So you should try

`"('ytz_q2', 99)"` not `'(ytz_q2, 99)'`. Because evaluating `ytz_q2` without quotes, is an undefined variable.

Comment: Ah I see, sure I can do that.